# Trouble with an .h import

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

As a beginner in ObjectiveC I need some help.

I'm working on a phonegap plugin for IOS (so, written with objective C). I use some open source code but I got an error with an .h import.

My architecture look like:

- myFmk.framework/
- myFmk.framework/ABCDE/myFmk.h  <== in a sub folder
- myFmk.framework/myFmk    <=== this is a file
- myPlugin.h
- myPlugin.m

In myPlugin.h I have #import and in "myFmk.framework/myFmk" file I have only one line "ABCDE/".

I thought that this file do a redirection of the absolute import (with brackets) but my complier told me that "myFmk/myFmk.h" is not found.

I tried to find some documentation about this feature but I wasn't able to find its name... do you have this documentation or the feature name?

Thks.

Comment: Check you framework search path and your header search paths in Build settings. I suspect your missing the headers because you haven't told it where to look.

Comment: As it's a framework, you should include only the framework, no specific .h files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the framework added using a cocoapod? If not, did you follow the instructions properly for adding it to your project? It would probably help if you posted the framework you are experiencing problems with.

If this is a framework that is added to your project properly and you are unable to import there are a few things you should check. First, go to your project settings (click on the project at the very top of your file tree in the left column) and then look for "linked libraries". See if the library is listed there. If not click the + and try to add it.

If this framework was added via cocoapods another thing to check is search your file structure for libPods.a. If it is red, I find sometimes it is helpful to delete it, close the project and run pod install again.

Also if you installed the project via cocoapods remember to open the workspace and not the old xcode project file.

I have also experienced this problem when my header search paths and other linker flag paths were wrong. Linker Flags should be $inherited if this is a cocoapod. In my projects most Header search paths are $inherited too.

If none of this is helpful please provide more information such as how this framework was added to your project and what the framework is. Also let us know if you get any error messages.